# Using external service providers with josso2

Tags: saml, josso

I am trying to setup Josso2.4 to work as a sign in solution to multiple websites. (Starting with just one).

I have configured my test web site as an "external saml2 service provider" in jooso but this require a "metadata file" and I have been unable to find any documentation for this metadata file format. Is it a standard saml format shared accross all saml implementations?

I found some sample xml files I could import, but i newer found a sample which had sso enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention, what you use as service provider. You can use Spring Security SAML and download metadata from special URL, for examle:  http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/metadata

See documentation: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/